# How would I go along with fetching same name values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this table in mysql

[image]

I'm trying to select the usernames that has the most records in this database and display it on a website. So basically I want to see which `username` is logged the most and display that username along with the count. It's a voting system tracking the amount of people that vote. I would like to display the top five voters from this table. So the top 5 usernames that are repeated the most.

Therefore:

[4] davidxd33

will be displayed on the website because this user has four votes and is logged in the database four times.

I've tried `SELECT username, count(username) FROM Votes` which only returned the first name in the database, then the total count of usernames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returns the top:

`SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS total FROM Votes GROUP BY username ORDER BY total DESC`

Thank you for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*)
FROM Votes
GROUP BY username
```

`GROUP BY` forces to return a line per `username`, and `COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows for each different `username`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username, 
count(*) as total 
FROM Vote
group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first group by usernames and then order them based on count in descending order and select the top 5. Hope this helps:-

select top 5 username, count(*) as votescount
from table t
group by username
order by votescount desc